# Can't load Metasploit after installation

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, metasploit

After istallation of Metaploit via [darkoperator/MSF-Installer](https://github.com/darkoperator/MSF-Installer) try to start the msfconsole and it return:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- /usr/local/bin/config/boot (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/local/bin/msfconsole:23:in `<main>'
```

using:

```
Linux ubuntu 3.13.0-32-generic
```

Have someone an idea?

Answer (score 15):

For me it helped following:

`sudo chmod o+r /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/robots-0.10.1/lib/robots.rb`

after that user is able to run metasploit.

Answer (score 3):

As user4170357 but with a slight difference due to: Mac OS X 10.9.5

to fix, run:

```
sudo chmod o+r /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/robots-0.10.1/lib/robots.rb
```

(path is a little bit different than original answer)

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in the kernel where file-system becomes read-only or inaccessible randomly. Read more [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1063354).

To fix Just reboot and it will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

From http://techlogbook.wordpress.com/2014/08/19/installing-metasploit-on-xubuntu-14-04/

> $ msfconsole
>   /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- /usr/local/bin/config/boot (LoadError)
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
>       from /usr/local/bin/msfconsole:23:in `'
>
> What I did was to edit /usr/local/bin/msfconsole line 23, and replace that line with:
>   `require File.expand_path('/usr/local/share/metasploit-framework/config/boot.rb', __FILE__)`
>
> Make sure that the path for config/boot.rb is correct for your system.
>
> Now, when I run msfconsole again, it gives me some warning of missing permission to write some log file.
>   `Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that /usr/local/share/metasploit-framework/log/production.log exists and is chmod 0666. The log level has been raised to WARN and the output directed to STDERR until the problem is fixed.`
>
> So I need to create the directory and make sure it is accessible.
>
> `$ cd /usr/local/share/metasploit-framework/`
>
> `$ mkdir log`
>
> `$ chmod 777 log`
>
> Now, I can run msfconsole. Before reaching the prompt, however, I got the following warning:
>
> [-] WARNING! The following modules could not be loaded!
>
> [-]    /usr/local/share/metasploit-framework/modules/auxiliary/scanner/smb/smb_login.rb: LoadError cannot load such file -- robots`

Maybe that can help you get started

Answer (score -1):

this might be becuase you bundled or installed metasploit as root you might need to get root access to run metasploit

Comment: this is not an answer, but a comment, please delete and wait until you have enough rep to comment.